# Is this the correct usage of the word "fraught"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

> MySpace is fraught with users sending friend requests to people they don't even know.

Comment: How about using "fraught" without its being followed by a prepositional phrase--e.g., "a fraught relationship"? It seems to be becoming more common, but it doesn't quite set right on my ears (or eyes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is correct here. If something is fraught with x, it is full of x. This x is usually a bad thing, and there is a lot of it. Here are a few xamples:

> - The journey was fraught with peril.
> - You failed the test because your answers were fraught with grammar mistakes.

Comment: +1 I would also point out that fraught is rather archaic sounding, and can have an unintentionally humorous effect at times. I sometimes like to use the word freighted in the same context just because it's a little fresher (although it comes from the same root). [I accidentally put this as an answer instead of a comment]

Comment: Next time I'm looking for a putdown, I will have to try out "Thou art fraught with excrement."

Comment: "The victim was fraught with fright after the fight"

Comment: According to the OED, fraught is used to describe *situations or a course of action*; I don't think it's applicable to a physical thing like a ship. It just sounds wrong.

Comment: @Elendil: Reading back, I think I agree that the ship example is a bit ramshackle. But why exactly? "Situations or a course of action" seems a bit too narrow: *a plain fraught with loose boulders and crevices*—does that sound wrong to you? How about this: because of its origin "freighted with", it is mostly restricted to situations that resemble a journey or a process; if used with a physical object, care must be taken that there should be no clash with the near-dead, but still faintly breathing metaphor.

Comment: ... A plain is not a vehicle, so that there is no clash; a ship is, so it should be *fraught with misfortune* or *fraught with incompetent sailors and second-rate cargo". Or is this too far-fetched?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if fraught can be applied to any physical thing, perhaps because I've only ever heard it in phrases like 'fraught with peril' or even 'She was fraught' (as in very upset). I see no technical reason why, it just doesn't 'gel' with me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary I just looked up the word fraught. It is actually an adjective. Which is odd because I’ve never seen adjectives applied this way but have definitely heard the phrase fraught with peril many times. It would be like saying it was blue with car.. wouldn’t you just say it was a blue car? I guess in olde English you could say an attribute was with something similar to the answer here saying the thing was full of the attribute. So the journey was full of an anxiety laden misfortune. Frought with misfortune.

Answer (score 0):

The synonym substitution test will ferret out spurious uses of "fraught."  If you can substitute the words "filled" or "loaded" for "fraught" with no change in intended meaning -- and without dangling denotation or semantic voids -- then it is probably proper usage.
Some modern dictionaries include a usage meaning for "fraught" without "with" (my 1978 Random House unabridged dictionary does not).  It should be remembered that dictionary entries are descriptive:  they inventory usage meanings that have currency within a speech community.  The inclusion of such uses should not be taken as an imprimatur of good diction.

Comment: Is fraught correctly used in the example in the question?

Comment: 'The inclusion of such uses should not be taken as an imprimatur of good diction.' Have you a recognised authority endorsing this opinion, Steve?